# How can dataweaver ignore producing xmlns in mule

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

I am doing an xml to xml transformation in mule dataweave component.
But the output produces " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" for every segment.
I hope there is no issues with it but is there a way I can set in dataweave to stop producing these lines.

Example Output from Dataweave:

```
<host>
         <event xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                id="app"
                time-event-applied="2015-08-10T15:14:40"
                user-id="user:admin"
                is-billable="N"
                entity="UNIT"
                entity-id="CHRS1501720"
                xsi:nil="true"/>
         <additional-info>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   id="X"
                   value="449"
                   xsi:nil="true"/>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   id="Y"
                   value="9431719"
                   xsi:nil="true"/>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   id="Z"
                   value="004"
                   xsi:nil="true"/>
         </additional-info>
      </host>
```

TIA

Comment: Defining a namespace for parent element should avoid namespaces for rest of the elements

Comment: @tortoise : I tried it. But no success. This is how I have defined : %namespace xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my problem.

### Example code from data weaver

```
info:{
  field @(id: "!23" , value: payload.Response.Detail.Header.ID  ): null
}
```

### Solution

```
info:{
  field @(id: "!23" , value: payload.Response.Detail.Header.ID  ): {}
}
```

So as obvious from my answer I just replace the null part with {} , then it stops producing

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using skipNullOn attribute on output directive?

[dataweave reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation)